# PostgreSql Full-Text Search forms of

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is it possible to do Full-text search in PostgreSql using morphological forms as it is done in Microsoft SQL Server with FORMSOF clause?

E.g. the field contains 'drank', I search 'drink' and find it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes".  Postgres does this by providing dictionaries, which are explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html).

Dictionaries come in different types, such as stop-words, synonyms, thesaurus, and ispell.  The latter does what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, example: I'd like to build the FTS with English morphological search. What I need to use? How to build the FTI?

Comment: @Oleg . . . I think the Postgres documentation covers that better and more completely than an answer on Stack Overflow would.

Comment: I have installed dictionaries as described in the Manual. But I did not find a way how to search the record with "cought" when I search "catch".

Comment: @Oleg . . . The correct word is "caught", with an "a", not an "o".

Comment: Yes, it is my error. But in any case: field contains "drank", "drunk", I try to search "drink" - no results. It seems I cannot find any irregular verbs